# How may I eliminate a gap appearing in a surface drawn with ParametricPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

What I did:

```
f[t_,z_] := Cos[z/2]^0.5 * (1 + HeavisideTheta[z - 0.35 Pi]);
ParametricPlot3D[{f[t, z] Cos[t], f[t, z] Sin[t], -z}, 
  {t, -Pi, Pi},{z, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
```

What I got:

[image]

The plot shows a gap in the surface that I wouldn't have expected just because the gradient is infinite.

What I want: The same image, but without the break.

Comment: Add `Exclusions -> None` to the options of your `ParametricPlot3D`.

Comment: "This question arises due to a simple mistake" Incorrect. "easily found in the documentation" That doesn't make it off topic. "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules" It already fits the rules -- see mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic . "This question appears to be off-topic for this site" is false and this question should not be on hold.

Comment: How is that not a simple mistake ?! Did you try searching the Q/A for similar questions ? Because If you did you would have found a dozen questions about the same thing. Also, it is easily found in the docs -- just try looking through the `Options` menu.

Comment: "This question already has an answer here: Why does Plot3D omit parts of the surface at kinks?" No. Different question and different problem, though same solution.

Comment: FTR, the false characterisation of this question as "off-topic" has now been rescinded. Thanks to whoever did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MarcoB says in his comment, add the option `Exclusions -> None`.

```
f[t_, z_] := Cos[z/2]^0.5*(1 + HeavisideTheta[z - 0.35 Pi]);
ParametricPlot3D[{f[t, z] Cos[t], f[t, z] Sin[t], -z}, 
  {t, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi},
  PlotRange -> All,
  Exclusions -> None]
```

plot[image]

Comment: Thanks. Works fine. I'd read " Exclusions   Automatic   u points or  curves to exclude" and never guessed what it was hiding. :-)